# JBoss EAP 6 - Secure the communications channels between clustered nodes

Tags: security, jboss-eap-6, jgroups

I'm studying for the "Redhat JBoss Admiministrator" certification. 
One of the neeeded competence is "Secure the communications channels between clustered nodes". Actually, the communication between two nodes in a cluster is done using the jgroups subsystem but i did not find in the documentation any reference to securing this communication.
Can you help to understand that point?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well JGroups happens to include a protocol called ENCRYPT that you should be able to use. Have a look into the JGroups documentation:

http://www.jgroups.org/manual/html/protlist.html

It's usally a bit fiddly to fit that into the XML format of the jgroups subsystem - probably the basic shape is gonna be

```
<protocol type="ENCRYPT">
    <property name="key_store_name">my.keystore</property>
    <property name="store_password">myStorePw</property>
    <property name="alias">myKeyAlias</property>
</protocol>
```

Disclaimer: I have not tried it yet.